# Add a search box to my dropdown list using PHP code

Tags: php

I want to add a search box to my drop down list like you see in the image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGwR4.jpg)

it's like i want to combine with a serch box and the dropdown list.
This is the code i used to creat my dropdown list :

```
   <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, "somapam_bd");

     $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT Nom FROM herboristes");

    while($ligne_liste=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo '<option value="'.$ligne_liste['Nom'].'">'.$ligne_liste['Nom']."</option>\n";
    }
    echo '</select>';
    ?>
```

Thank you :)

Comment: You'll need js for that; what attempt(s) have you made to try and resolve this yourself?

Comment: and did you open `<select>`?

Comment: Requires JS, likely something like jQuery select2 plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How search into options of select tag html without plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713621/how-search-into-options-of-select-tag-html-without-plugin)

Comment: and what does this have to do with [dropbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dropbox)? do you know what that is?

Comment: @Fred-ii- : I did try some codes but it didn't work

Comment: @MohamedRedaAguezzoul You wil need to update your question containing what you tried. At least that will show an effort on your part and you may have made an error somewhere that others/I might be able to help and see.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i understand what do you mean , but i just need some suggestions to work with thank you.

Comment: @MohamedRedaAguezzoul see the link that Tom placed earlier.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i did try it but it gives me a search box a part of my  dropdown list. What i want is to combine both of them. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution is using the "chosen plugin" for wordpress but i had another problem is that i got one more dropdown list in the main menu so i don't know how i delet it.
this is the JQuery code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $('select:not(#mo-fonts)').chosen({ width:"95%" });});
```

thank u !